# Get certificate thumbprint from pfx in Inno Setup

Tags: ssl, inno-setup

I'm trying to configure HTTPS connection for my web service from Inno Setup installer. Previously, I was doing next things:

1. Created self-signed server certificate with `makecert`
2. Installed certificate to Local Machine Personal certificates using `certmgr`
3. Obtained its thumbprint/hash using `GetSHA1OfFile` method of Inno Setup.
4. Assigned certificate to port using `netsh http add sslcert` command

But now I'm switching from `makecert` to OpenSSL, and also introducing CA certificate, which is previously generated, and works as issuer for my server certificate. What am I doing now:

1. Install CA certificate, using `certmgr`
2. Generate server certificate from CA certificate, using OpenSSL. Server certificate consists of actual certificate and private key
3. Combine certificate and private key to pfx file format, using OpenSSL
4. Install pfx file, using `CertUtil`

Now, the issue is, when generating certificate with OpenSSL, it seems, that its sha1 hash is different from its thumbprint, so I can't use `GetSHA1OfFile` for this purpose anymore.

So, question is - how can I programmatically get certificate hash in Inno Setup, to assign it to port, if `GetSHA1OfFile` can't be used for this purpose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`certutil.exe -dump` command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/certutil#-dump) and read its output.

I'm not sure, which of the fingerprints you are after, but I assume it's the one labelled `Cert Hash(sha1)`.

```pascal
var
  Key: string;
  I: Integer;
  TempFile: string;
  Lines: TArrayOfString;
  Hash: string;
  ResultCode: Integer;
  PfxFile: string;
  Params: string;
begin
  PfxFile := '...\my.pfx';
  TempFile := ExpandConstant('{tmp}\certdump.txt');
  Params := '/c certutil.exe -dump "' + PfxFile + '" > "' + TempFile + '"';
  if not Exec('cmd.exe', Params, '', SW_HIDE, ewWaitUntilTerminated, ResultCode) then
  begin
    Log('Failed to run certificate dump');
  end
    else
  if not LoadStringsFromFile(TempFile, Lines) then
  begin
    Log('Failed to read certificate dump');
  end
    else
  begin
    Key := 'Cert Hash(sha1):';
    Hash := '';
    for I := 0 to GetArrayLength(Lines) - 1 do
    begin
      if CompareText(Copy(Lines[I], 1, Length(Key)), Key) = 0 then
      begin
        Hash := Trim(Copy(Lines[I], Length(Key) + 1, Length(Lines[I]) - Length(Key)));
        StringChange(Hash, ' ', '');
      end;
    end;
    DeleteFile(TempFile);

    if Hash = '' then
    begin
      Log('Hash not found in certificate dump');
    end
      else
    begin
      Log('Certificate hash: ' + Hash);
    end;
  end;
end;
```